# Access token Refresh - Best practices

Tags: java, rest, oauth, access-token, spring-restcontroller

I am writing a wrapper to existing third-party REST apis. **access-token** of the third-party expires in an hour. So i don't want to fetch new token everytime and decided to use the old token and if it fails with unAuthorized exception, i want to fetch new access token then make a call again.. I wrote below code for it.

```
public Store getVendor(String url,boolean tokenreseted) throws Exception {

    Store store =null;
    try {
        store = (Store) RestClient.get(url, headers, queryparam, Store.class);
    } 
    catch (UnauthorizedException e) { 
        if(!tokenreseted) {  //Try with new Access token. 
            accessToken=getAccessToken();
            return getVendor(url,true);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("UnauthorizedException exception", e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error occured while getting storeIds",e);
    }

    return store;
}
```

Above code works.. But is it good practice? or is there any other better way to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `expiryTime` since you know that your **access-token** will expire in an hour. Try the following.

1. Get Access Token. Store in an `Object` with the token and
   `expiryTime`.
2. Generate request only when currentTime + 30 seconds < = `expiryTime` . 30 Seconds is  small threshold to create a new access token.
3. If not, create a new Token and update the `Object` with new token and `expiryTime` and call the API.

Answer (score 1):

use org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate. ..https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html

Below is the code which can be used:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate rteClient(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {

    OAuth2RestTemplate rteClient = new OAuth2RestTemplate(rte(), oauth2ClientContext);
    rteClient.setAccessTokenProvider(buildAccessTokenProvider());   
    return rteClient;
}

private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails rte() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails rte = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    rte.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    rte.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
    rte.setClientId("clientId");
    rte.setClientSecret("clientSecret");
    rte.setAccessTokenUri("http://..");
    return rte;
}

private ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider buildAccessTokenProvider() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException { 
    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
    return accessTokenProvider;
}
```

Autowire the above bean to call the api with token. it takes care of expiry before making call..